# JPA XML Mapping file resolves just fine, but fails to resolve when running as a JUnit test

Tags: java, xml, spring, jpa, junit

I have a spring project with an XML-setup entity manager factory, part of which points to an external mapping file that contains all of my queries.

Here are the versions I am using:

Spring version: 4.1.1.RELEASE

JUnit version: 4.9

Spring-data-jpa version: 1.7.1.RELEASE

Java version: 1.8

The problem here is that my project worked fine before I tried to add a JUnit test class to my application.  In fact, the project started with zero errors and I could run every query without a hitch.  Now that I have added a test class, it fails because during the unit test it tries to setup the application context and fails to resolve my mapping file. (from what I can decipher in the stack trace)  Why??

The file I am trying to load is `queries.xml` and it is located in `src/main/resources`  here is the file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd" 
version="2.1">

<named-query name="GameSet.getNewTutorial">
    <query>
        <![CDATA[
            SELECT gs
            FROM GameSet gs
            WHERE gs.id.gameCatCd = :qstnSet
            AND gs.presetQstn.id.qstnSet = 'tutorials'
            ORDER BY gs.qstnOrder ASC
        ]]>
    </query>
</named-query>

<named-query name="WkstHdr.getExistingWorksheet">
    <query>
        <![CDATA[
            SELECT wh
            FROM WkstHdr wh
            WHERE wh.id.startDate BETWEEN :beginTimestamp AND :endTimestamp
            AND wh.id.warriorId = :warriorId
            AND wh.id.qstnSet = :qstnSet
        ]]>
    </query>
</named-query>

<named-query name="GameSet.getNewWorksheet">
    <query>
        <![CDATA[
            SELECT gs
            FROM GameSet gs
            WHERE gs.presetQstn.id.qstnSet = :qstnSet
        ]]>
    </query>
</named-query>

<named-query name="WkstVal.getExistingTutorial">
    <query>
        <![CDATA[
            SELECT v
            FROM WkstVal v
            WHERE v.id.warriorId = :warriorId
            AND v.id.gameCatCd = :qstnSet
            AND v.id.qstnSet = 'tutorials'
            ORDER BY v.gameSet.qstnOrder
        ]]>
    </query>
</named-query>

<named-native-query name="Score.getScore" result-set-mapping="ScoreMapping">
    <query>
        <![CDATA[
            SELECT sum(CASE WHEN v.bool_resp = true THEN pq.points ELSE 0 END) / :total AS points,
            sum(CASE WHEN ((v.game_cat_cd = 'summary') AND (v.game_sub_cat_cd = 'zone') AND (v.num_resp > 0)) THEN v.num_resp ELSE 0 END) /
            (CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN :total = 1 THEN 1 ELSE (sum(CASE WHEN ((v.game_cat_cd = 'summary') AND (v.game_sub_cat_cd = 'zone') AND (v.num_resp > 0)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) END) > 0 THEN (CASE WHEN :total = 1 THEN 1 ELSE (sum(CASE WHEN ((v.game_cat_cd = 'summary') AND (v.game_sub_cat_cd = 'zone') AND (v.num_resp > 0)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) END) ELSE 1 END) AS zone,
            sum(CASE WHEN ((v.game_cat_cd = 'summary') AND (v.game_sub_cat_cd = 'power')) THEN v.num_resp ELSE 0 END) / :total AS power
            FROM preset_qstn pq JOIN game_set gs JOIN wkst_hdr wh JOIN wkst_val v 
            ON wh.warrior_id = v.warrior_id
            AND wh.qstn_set = v.qstn_set
            AND wh.start_date = v.start_date 
            ON gs.game_cat_cd = v.game_cat_cd
            AND gs.game_sub_cat_cd = v.game_sub_cat_cd
            AND gs.game_cd = v.game_cd
            AND gs.qstn_cd = v.qstn_cd 
            ON pq.qstn_set = gs.qstn_set
            AND pq.qstn_cd = gs.qstn_cd
            WHERE wh.warrior_id = :warriorId
            AND wh.qstn_set = :qstnSet
            AND wh.start_date BETWEEN :beginTimestamp AND :endTimestamp
        ]]>
    </query>
</named-native-query>

<named-native-query name="Task.getTasks" result-set-mapping="TaskMapping">
    <query>
        <![CDATA[
            SELECT "public"."wkst_hdr"."start_date" AS startDate,
            "public"."wkst_hdr"."cmpl_date" AS cmplDate,
            "public"."wkst_val"."bool_resp" AS important,
            "public"."wkst_val"."txt_resp" AS description 
            FROM "public"."wkst_hdr" 
            JOIN "public"."wkst_val" 
            ON "public"."wkst_hdr"."warrior_id" = "public"."wkst_val"."warrior_id" 
            AND "public"."wkst_hdr"."start_date" = "public"."wkst_val"."start_date" 
            AND "public"."wkst_hdr"."qstn_set" = "public"."wkst_val"."qstn_set" 
            WHERE "public"."wkst_hdr"."warrior_id" = :warriorId 
            AND "public"."wkst_hdr"."qstn_set" = 'todos' 
            ORDER BY "public"."wkst_hdr"."start_date" DESC, 
            "public"."wkst_val"."bool_resp" DESC
        ]]>
    </query>
</named-native-query>

<sql-result-set-mapping name="ScoreMapping">
    <constructor-result target-class="com.wakeupwarrior.model.api.Score">
        <column name="zone" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
        <column name="points" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
        <column name="power" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    </constructor-result>
</sql-result-set-mapping>

<sql-result-set-mapping name="TaskMapping">
    <constructor-result target-class="com.wakeupwarrior.model.api.Task">
        <column name="startDate" class="java.util.Date"/>
        <column name="cmplDate" class="java.util.Date"/>
        <column name="description" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <column name="important" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
    </constructor-result>
</sql-result-set-mapping>
```

I have a context file for the main application and I have a context file for the JUnit testing, they are both EXACTLY the same.  Below is a copy of my context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model and pageable -->  
<annotation-driven>
    <argument-resolvers>
        <beans:bean id="sortResolver" class="org.springframework.data.web.SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver" />
        <beans:bean id="pageableResolver" class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver">
            <beans:constructor-arg ref="sortResolver" />
        </beans:bean>
    </argument-resolvers>
</annotation-driven>


<!-- Enables Spring to bootstrap the correct packages, looking for components -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.slconnected.*" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wakeupwarrior.*" />


    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for the index.html file -->
<resources mapping="/*" location="/" />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by serving static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<resources mapping="/node_modules/**" location="/node_modules/" />

<resources mapping="/themes/**" location="/themes/" />


<!-- Resolves messages on error inputs -->
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
</beans:bean>


<!-- Adds properties from warrior-db.properties -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="location" value="classpath:warrior-db.properties" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Warrior DB data source with c3p0 connection pool-->
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <!-- Connection properties -->
    <beans:property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClass}" />
    <beans:property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.jdbcUrl}" />
    <beans:property name="user" value="${jdbc.user}" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <!-- Pool properties -->
    <beans:property name="minPoolSize" value="${jdbc.minPoolSize}" />
    <beans:property name="maxPoolSize" value="${jdbc.maxPoolSize}" />
    <beans:property name="acquireIncrement" value="${jdbc.acquireIncrement}" />
    <beans:property name="maxStatements" value="${jdbc.maxStatements}" />
    <beans:property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${jdbc.idleConnectionTestPeriod}" />
    <beans:property name="loginTimeout" value="${jdbc.loginTimeout}" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Entity Manager Factory -->
<beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.wakeupwarrior.model.warriordb" />
    <beans:property name="mappingResources">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>
                classpath:queries.xml
            </beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="jpaProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">
                org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
            </beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <beans:property name="databasePlatform" value="${jdbc.databasePlatform}" />
            <beans:property name="showSql" value="${jdbc.showSql}" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Enables Transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />

<!-- Annotation config -->
<context:annotation-config/>
```

If I comment out this part:

`<beans:property name="mappingResources">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>
                    classpath:queries.xml
                </beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>`

Everything seems to run great!  ..other than the fact that I can't use my queries now, so this doesn't solve my problem.

Here is the stack trace that I get when I try to run:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/slconnected/test/WarriorTests-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.MappingException: Unable to resolve explicitly named mapping-file : 
                classpath:queries.xml
             : origin(
                classpath:queries.xml
            )
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:132)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:59)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:260)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:63)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:169)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:199)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:253)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:216)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:82)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:67)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:162)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.MappingException: Unable to resolve explicitly named mapping-file : 
                classpath:queries.xml
             : origin(
                classpath:queries.xml
            )
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.applyScanResultsToManagedResources(ScanningCoordinator.java:213)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:81)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:98)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:200)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:150)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider$1.<init>(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
... 40 more
ERROR: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@31f924f5] to prepare test instance [com.slconnected.test.WarriorTests@27dc79f7]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:169)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:199)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:253)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:216)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:82)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:67)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:162)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/slconnected/test/WarriorTests-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.MappingException: Unable to resolve explicitly named mapping-file : 
                classpath:queries.xml
             : origin(
                classpath:queries.xml
            )
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:132)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:59)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:260)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:63)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:83)
... 25 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.MappingException: Unable to resolve explicitly named mapping-file : 
                classpath:queries.xml
             : origin(
                classpath:queries.xml
            )
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.applyScanResultsToManagedResources(ScanningCoordinator.java:213)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:81)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:98)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:200)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:150)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider$1.<init>(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
... 40 more
```

Again, everything runs perfectly when running the project normally.  It is only when I run it as a test case, or when I get to the testing part of the build that I get this error.   What is going on here?  How do I get it to work with my external query.xml file during unit testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FIGURED IT OUT!!!!

I spent several days stepping thousands of lines of code in a debugger until I was able to watch the problem in action.  It turns out there is a line of code in a class deep in hibernate `org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl` it attempts to locate the file on the classpath using the following code:

```
final URL url = getAggregatedClassLoader().getResource( name );
        if ( url != null ) {
            return url;
        }
```

There were a total of two problems here.  First, the process the file name string followed when trying to resolve the file did not allow for the stripping of the line breaks and spaces copied from the `queries.xml` file.  The last problem was that `getResource()` returns null if you DO NOT append `classpath:` during production, but returns null if you DO append `classpath:` while running as JUnit.  I have no idea why this happens, but it does.  So, my solution was to modify my context file used for JUnit testing to use:

```
<beans:property name="mappingResources">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>queries.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
```

instead of:

```
<beans:property name="mappingResources">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>
                classpath:queries.xml
            </beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
```

Thus I ended up with a modified test application context as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">


<!-- Enables Spring to bootstrap the correct packages, looking for components -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.slconnected.*" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wakeupwarrior.*" />


<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model and pageable -->  
<annotation-driven>
    <argument-resolvers>
        <beans:bean id="sortResolver" class="org.springframework.data.web.SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver" />
        <beans:bean id="pageableResolver" class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver">
            <beans:constructor-arg ref="sortResolver" />
        </beans:bean>
    </argument-resolvers>
</annotation-driven>


<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for the index.html file -->
<resources mapping="/*" location="/" />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by serving static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<resources mapping="/node_modules/**" location="/node_modules/" />

<resources mapping="/themes/**" location="/themes/" />


<!-- Resolves messages on error inputs -->
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
</beans:bean>


<!-- View resolver that works by registering beans with names -->
<beans:bean id="beanNameResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="order" value="1" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- The Birt engine factory -->
<beans:bean id="engine" class="com.wakeupwarrior.reports.core.BirtEngineFactory" />

<!-- Resolves POWER FOCUS HTML view -->
<beans:bean name="html/powerFocus" id="html/powerFocus" class="com.wakeupwarrior.reports.core.HtmlSingleFormatBirtView">
    <beans:property name="birtEngine" ref="engine" />
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="reportName" value="power_focus.rptdesign" />
    <beans:property name="reportsDirectory" value="reports" />  
</beans:bean>

<!-- Resolves TESTER HTML view -->
<beans:bean name="html/tester" id="html/tester" class="com.wakeupwarrior.reports.core.HtmlSingleFormatBirtView">
    <beans:property name="birtEngine" ref="engine" />
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="reportName" value="tester.rptdesign" />
    <beans:property name="reportsDirectory" value="reports" />  
</beans:bean>   


<!-- Adds properties from warrior-db.properties -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="location" value="classpath:warrior-db.properties" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Warrior DB data source with c3p0 connection pool-->
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <!-- Connection properties -->
    <beans:property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClass}" />
    <beans:property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.jdbcUrl}" />
    <beans:property name="user" value="${jdbc.user}" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <!-- Pool properties -->
    <beans:property name="minPoolSize" value="${jdbc.minPoolSize}" />
    <beans:property name="maxPoolSize" value="${jdbc.maxPoolSize}" />
    <beans:property name="acquireIncrement" value="${jdbc.acquireIncrement}" />
    <beans:property name="maxStatements" value="${jdbc.maxStatements}" />
    <beans:property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${jdbc.idleConnectionTestPeriod}" />
    <beans:property name="loginTimeout" value="${jdbc.loginTimeout}" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Entity Manager Factory -->
<beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.wakeupwarrior.model.*" />
    <beans:property name="mappingResources">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>queries.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="jpaProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">
                org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
            </beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <beans:property name="databasePlatform" value="${jdbc.databasePlatform}" />
            <beans:property name="showSql" value="${jdbc.showSql}" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Enables Transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />

<!-- Annotation config -->
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Works perfectly now!